# Can Email Links open in new window?

Tags: email, hyperlink, new-window

I have this line of code:

```
<a href="mailto:test@hotmail.com?subject=test&body=test" target="_blank">test</a>
```

But the `target="_blank"` is not working. It always opens the mail server in the same window but not in new. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like your code got posted correctly.

Comment: target only applies to browser windows. the user's mail client is **NOT** going to embed itself in their browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It always opens the mail server in the same window but not in new.

You've got *no* control over how the user's client will handle `mailto:` URLs. It may choose to ignore them completely (as my client does), it may start up a new program such as `mutt` or `pine` or `kmail` or `thunderbird`, or whatever; or it might even load a web-mail client using a browser-specific plugin.

You cannot control what happens on the client's machine when handling a `mailto:` URL -- you'd better not waste your time trying to fiddle with it, because it will only ever be meaningful on your development machine.